# Angular 8 + Django RestFramework file(csv) download

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am new to angular. I want to download a CSV, on click of download button.

django viewset

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def download_csv(self, request):
        data = {
          "student_data": [
            {
              "roll_no": 12,
              "detail": {
                "name": "Tom",
                "address": "XYZ"
              }
            },
            {
              "roll_no": 8,
              "detail": {
                "name": "Ryan",
                "address": "ABC"
              }
            },
            {
              "roll_no": 12,
              "detail": {
                "name": "Tom",
                "address": "PQR"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="emp_details.csv"'
        writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=['name', 'roll', 'address'])
        writer.writeheader()
        for i in data["student_data"]:
            meta_data = i["detail"]
            detail_dict = {}
            detail_dict["name"] = meta_data["name"]
            detail_dict["address"] = meta_data["address"]
            detail_dict["roll"] = i["roll"]
            writer.writerow(address)
        return response
```

When i am hitting URL http://localhost:8000/download_csv/ . CSV is downloaded with file name "emp_details.csv".

Now i want to integrate this response with anuglar. on click of download button from angular front-end, how do I subscribe to this API endpoint and download the csv file. which is the response(not usual JSON) of this end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. with below code

component

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

onDownloadClick() 
    {
      this.serviceModule.download().subscribe(
        (res) => {
          let blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/csv' });
          FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "example.csv")
        }
      );
    }
```

service

```
public download(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(
        "http://localhost:8000/download_csv/",
        { responseType: "arraybuffer" }
      )
  }
```

hope this helps someone in future!

Comment: What si the beginning of your python file ? Inside your .ts file, when you do your .get you don’t need to put the name of your python code ? Thank you